# How to jump in Unity?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I wanna know how to make my character(which is actually a capsule) to jump...

I created a script but my character jump only once when I press **space key** why?

Here's my whole code>>>

```
    using UnityEngine;

public class PlayerMovement : MonoBehaviour
{

public Rigidbody rb;
public float forwardForce = 1000f;
public float backwardForce = -1000f;
public float leftwardForce = -500f;
public float rightwardForce = 500f;
public float jump = 500f;
bool isJumping = false;

void FixedUpdate()
{
    if (Input.GetKey("w"))
    {
        rb.AddForce(0, 0 , forwardForce * Time.deltaTime);
    }
    if(Input.GetKey("s")){

        rb.AddForce(0 , 0 , backwardForce* Time.deltaTime);
    }
    if(Input.GetKey("a")){

        rb.AddForce(leftwardForce * Time.deltaTime , 0 , 0);
    }
    if (Input.GetKey("d"))
    {
        rb.AddForce(rightwardForce * Time.deltaTime , 0 ,0);
    }
    if(Input.GetKey("space") && !isJumping){
        rb.AddForce(0 , jump * Time.deltaTime , 0 , ForceMode.ChangeVelocity);
        isJumping = true;
    }



}
```

}

Don't worry about anything everything is fine except my jump script>>>>

Comment: Nothing  you showed sets is jumping to false. This must be on SO somewhere cos it sure comes up enough

Comment: If your jump is executed the way it is, you shouldn't calculate the jump as `jump * Time.deltaTime` and instead just use `jump`, since the delta time doesn't apply in this case.

Comment: Your problem is clear, you set isJumping to true and never set it back to false so it can never enter that "if(Input.GetKey("space") && !isJumping)" statement again.

Comment: I have one more problem when I hold space button it constantly add the force in upward direction..

Answer (score 0):

```
   if(Input.GetKey("space") && !isJumping){
     rb.AddForce(0 , jump * Time.deltaTime , 0 , ForceMode.ChangeVelocity);
     isJumping = true;
   }
```

Here, you have a test that will be true if and only if you press space, and isjumping is wrong.
But, you put is jumping at true if this condition is passed. Where do you put the variable isjumping at "False" again ? Here isJumping is probably true forever

You have to know when the character isn't jumping anymore (when he touch the ground) so you can put isJumping at False, so you can redo a jump.